# lightning-record-edit-form: display text field as a custom picklist?

Tags: lightning-web-components, picklist

I've created a custom object where the user manually enters a locale value (ex: en_US, es).  Instead of letting the user manually enter a locale, I'd like to provide the user with a combo box of valid options to select from.  (The options would be a subset of the supported languages selected in the org, retrieved via Apex.)  In Visualforce, there was a way to accomplish this by overriding the default page layout and supplying your own custom VF page, which would include a `<apex:selectList>` for a given text field, and the select options retrieved via Apex.

Is it possible to do the same thing with `<lightning-record-edit-form>`, where an `<lightning-input-field>` can be defined as picklist values supplied via a wired lookup?  Or can a  include a `<lightning-combobox>`?  I was hoping there would be an easy way to accomplish what I need in LWC without having to recreate the entire record layout from scratch.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there anything preventing you from changing the field type to an unrestricted picklist and then using the native functionality of picklist labels & values?

Comment: @MarkPond The pick list values and labels need to be dynamically retrieved.  They are a subset of the org's selected languages.  I also don't want the user to just type in anything, since they could easily mistype a location code.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use `lightning-combobox` instead of `lightning-input-field` and populate the options and values from either Apex or from JS using `RecordUI`.

Comment: do you have an example?